# Inverse relation returns null using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a simple one-to-many relationship, where one authentication type has many client:

```
class Client extends Model {

    protected $table = 'client';
    protected $primaryKey = 'client_id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'client_id',
        'auth_type_id',

    ];

    public function auth()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\AuthType', 'foreign_key', 'id');
    }
}

class AuthType extends Model {

    protected $table = 'authType';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name'
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'foreign_key', 'auth_type_id');
    }


}
```

So what I want is, to access the name of the authentication, when the $client is known.

```
 $authType = $client->auth();
 $authType->name;
```

And I get:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name
```

How can I access the name property of Auth, if I have a Client ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the relation result you have to use

```
$authType = $client->auth;
```

If you use `$client->auth()` you'll get back a `BelongsTo` relation.

Comment: OK, I tried $client->auth; and I get null; The SQL executed is ''select * from `authType` where `authType`.`id` is null limit 1'  I'm not sure why the null is set in this case?

Comment: Does your tables really contain a column `foreign_key` or did you just copy that from the Laravel docs? You client table should have a `auth_type_id` column and that's it. You don't need to specify foreign and local keys in your relations if you are using Laravels conventions.

Comment: authType table contains: id, name; client table contains: auth_type_id, client_id. This is direct info from MySQL.  When creating a table, I used this statement in migration for the user table:  $table->foreign('auth_type_id')->references('id')->on('authType');

Comment: Update your relations to this:
`return $this->belongsTo('App\AuthType');`
`return $this->hasMany('App\User');`

and try again. Also: you have data in these columns, right?

Comment: Updated, and I still get null; Yes I have data. The thing is, if I use  AuthType::find($client->auth_type_id); it will find the right AuthType object.

Comment: Can you post the output of dd($client) ?

Comment: OK, I updated the code, but $client->auth still returns null, I also had to use return $this->hasOne('App\AuthType', 'id'); because without 'id', sql was trying to use 'authType.client_id' instead of 'authType.id'. Weird..